# Checking for null, == null vs != null

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a recommended way (according to .net Framework guidelines) of checking for null, example:

```
if (value == null)
{//code1}
else
{//code2}
```

or

```
if (value != null)
{//code2}
else
{//code1}
```

Or the both codes has same performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no performance difference, so you should strive for improved readability.

For example, it is often a good idea to put the more "regular" path in the `if` branch, and put the "exceptional" one in the `else` branch.

Comment: "There is no performance difference, so you should code for readability" --- actually it's always a good idea to write a readable code at first place :-)

Comment: @zerkms, well, that's a good starting point.  But if your profiling surfaces bottlenecks, you will sometimes have to sacrifice at the altar of readability.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: yep, but only **after** you've written beautiful piece of code. Well designed code is easier to improve (from performance point of view)

Answer (score 15):

Both options will perform identically.

You should use whichever one makes sense semantically, or whichever one results in cleaner code.
For example, if the non-null action is shorter, it makes sense to put that block first, so that the `else` is close to the `if`.

Comment: Or use `value == null ? code1 : code2` if you want! Lots of ways to skin a cat

Comment: @zerkms, is it because you despise the `?` operator?  I see no problem with Charleh's suggestion.

Comment: @Slaks, I wish more people would put the shorter block first, I cringe when I see 40 lines in a block, the else, then a single line of code...

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I do like it, but yesterday I had worked with 3 levels of nest (I mean a binary 3 with height = 3, so the total amount of ternary operators was ~6 or 7) of ternary operators in one expression. And the only reason for that was that author wanted to look cool, because it could be implemented using `if` in a much more readable manner. So, perhaps today I despise it ;-)

Comment: @zerkms, fair enough -- in which case we both essentially agree with Daniel above. :)

Comment: Haha - I'd never use the ternary for more than 1 operation... if you've ever used SQL Server Reporting Services report designer and didn't know about the `choose` or `switch` functions....I suffered for a while there...

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference in performance. I personally put the more common case on top and the less common case in the `else` branch but that's just preference. This makes it easier for me to see the more common scenario.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference. Use them as per your need(readability/usability perspective). **Most appropriate/used block goes in `if` and the optional/secondary block goes in `else`.**

Answer (score 0):

both are same.. for readability you can put the block of code in IF which gives the result as true. In this case IF(value != null) is better readable and obvious :)